# error: no matching function for call to ‘Point::Point()

Tags: c++, class

So i created the class Point and want to use it as the parameter of the constructor in the class Circle , but the error : There is no default constructor for class "Point" shows up and I dont know how to fix it. The code is represented below this text:

```
class Point {
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int X, int  Y) {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }

};


class Circle {
private:
    int radius;
    Point centre;

public:
    Circle(Point q, int r) {
        centre = q;
        radius = r;


    }


};

int main() {
    Point obj = Point(3, 4);
   Circle obj = Circle(obj, 3);




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **first problem** is that when the constructor `Circle::Cirlce(Point, int)` is implicitly called by the compiler, before executing the body of that ctor, the data members `centre` and `radius` are **default initialized**. But since you've provided a **user-defined ctor** `Point::Point(int, int)` for class `Point`, the compiler will not synthesize the **default ctor** `Point::Point()`. Thus, the data member `centre` cannot be default initialized.

To **solve** this you can use **constructor initializer list** as shown below. The constructor initializer list shown below, **copy initialize** the data member `centre` instead of default initializing it.

```
class Point {
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int X, int  Y) {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }

};
class Circle {
private:
    int radius;
    Point centre;

public:
//--------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--->constructor initializer list used here
    Circle(Point q, int r): radius(r), centre(q)
    {
     
    }
};

int main() {
    Point obj = Point(3, 4);
   Circle circleObj(obj,4);
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/pAFqht3DJ)

Additionally, you had 2 objects with the same name `obj` inside `main`.