# How to avoid new when "error: no viable overloaded '='"?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I think I have a fundamental misunderstand of how objects are being constructed.

I have some code that is currently constructing objects using `new` which I've been told is bad practice. So I figured I could take the `new` keyword out, replace my pointer with actual objects, and remove the `delete` statements. Unfortunately, when I remove the new statement, I get `error: no viable overloaded '='`. I don't understand why.

The object I'm trying to make is a `LightWeightNeuralNetwork`; see https://github.com/lwtnn/lwtnn/blob/master/include/lwtnn/LightweightNeuralNetwork.hh

*Edit: it has been pointed out in the comments by UnholySheep that `LightweightNeuralNetwork` has no default constructor, and this is the source of the problem (when the class `TNeuralNetworkLWTNN` is initialised, it somehow needs default constructors for all member objects?). Unfortunately, the  solution in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910536/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-pointpoint) proposed as a dupe will not work, as that solution requires the problem object is created in the initializer list. `LightweightNeuralNetwork` needs a file to be opened before it can be created.*

My code is normally compiled as part of a larger framework, but here is a toy model that demonstrates the relevant bits.

A header file;

```cpp
#ifndef VNEURALNETWORKLWTNN_H
#define VNEURALNETWORKLWTNN_H

#include <iostream>

// Becuase we have a field of type LightweightNeuralNetwork
#include "lwtnn/LightweightNeuralNetwork.hh"

class TNeuralNetworkLWTNN {
public:
  // same as for lwtnn
  typedef std::map<std::string, double> NetworkInputs;
  typedef std::map<std::string, double> NetworkOutputs;

  // constructor and destructor
  explicit TNeuralNetworkLWTNN(std::string inputFile);
  ~TNeuralNetworkLWTNN();

  // business end
  NetworkOutputs compute(NetworkInputs inputs);

private:
  // !!Change this to not be a pointer!!
  lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork * lwtnn_neural;
};

#endif
```

and a class;

```cpp
#include "TNeuralNetworkLWTNN.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

// LWTNN
#include "lwtnn/LightweightNeuralNetwork.hh"
#include "lwtnn/parse_json.hh"

TNeuralNetworkLWTNN::TNeuralNetworkLWTNN(std::string inputFile) {
  // The input file is read into a stringstream
  std::ifstream input(inputFile);
  std::stringstream sin;
  sin << input.rdbuf();
  input.close();
  // build the graph
  lwt::JSONConfig config = lwt::parse_json(sin);
  // !! I don't want to be using new !!
  // !! Change this to just use '=' !!
  // !! error: no viable overloaded '=' !!
  lwtnn_neural = new lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork(config.inputs, config.layers,
                                                   config.outputs);
};

// I'd rather not need any code here
TNeuralNetworkLWTNN::~TNeuralNetworkLWTNN(){
  delete lwtnn_neural;
};

TNeuralNetworkLWTNN::NetworkOutputs
TNeuralNetworkLWTNN::compute(TNeuralNetworkLWTNN::NetworkInputs inputs) {
  // !! Change this to use . not -> !!
  TNeuralNetworkLWTNN::NetworkOutputs outputs =
      TNeuralNetworkLWTNN::lwtnn_neural->compute(inputs);
  return outputs;
};
```

Apologies for not producing something you can compile, I don't have access to the library lwtnn outside the framework I'm writing in. I'm hopeful that my mistake is quite basic.

Complete error message (with some paths modified);

```
/path/to/repo/TNeuralNetworkLWTNN.cxx:9:22: error: constructor for 'TNeuralNetworkLWTNN' must explicitly initialize the member 'lwtnn_neural' which does not have a default constructor
TNeuralNetworkLWTNN::TNeuralNetworkLWTNN(std::string inputFile)
                     ^
/path/to/repo/TNeuralNetworkLWTNN.h:36:34: note: member is declared here
  lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork  lwtnn_neural;
                                 ^
/path/to/library/lwtnn/LightweightNeuralNetwork.hh:41:9: note: 'lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork' declared here
  class LightweightNeuralNetwork
        ^
/path/to/repo/TNeuralNetworkLWTNN.cxx:18:16: error: no viable overloaded '='
  lwtnn_neural = lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork(config.inputs, config.layers,
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/to/releases/lwtnn/2.11.1-2ee64/x86_64-centos7-gcc11-opt/include/lwtnn/LightweightNeuralNetwork.hh:52:31: note: candidate function not viable: expects an lvalue for 1st argument
    LightweightNeuralNetwork& operator=(LightweightNeuralNetwork&) = delete;
                              ^
2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/GenericTest.dir/TNeuralNetworkLWTNN.cxx.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/GenericTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please post a complete error message. However it seems that `lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork` is not copyable or movable. Also is this specifically about avoiding dynamic memory allocations or only `new` and `delete`? Because `std::unique_ptr` would solve the latter problem

Comment: Do not rely on "authoritative" statements like "using `new` is bad practice". Learn the difference between static and dynamic allocation and the reasons why they exist.

Comment: @UnholySheep I think I want the latter. That's would meet the requirements of good practice right? So I should use `std::unique_ptr`? Error message added.

Comment: @YvesDaoust while I get what your saying, I also get how `new` could be dangerous. For example; could a subclass overriding the destructor and forget to delete the network? I just don't know that much about c++ yet. So this request seems well motivated to me.

Comment: `new` is not "dangerous", bugs are dangerous.  Learn the difference between static and dynamic allocation and the reasons why they exist.

Comment: An inheriting class cannot "disable" a parent destructor. However your class does not adhere to the rule of 0/3/5 as it is missing copy constructor/assignment (or move constructor/assignment), which is a bug. A `std::unique_ptr` member variable will disable implicit generation of copy operations (and thereby fix the bug)

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm reading about `std::unique_ptr` I think your right, that's what I should have used. Can I ask about the question linked? It seems to imply that I should have created the `LightweightNeuralNetwork` in the initializer list. That seems impossible, given I need to open the file before I can pass it to `LightweightNeuralNetwork`?

Comment: That duplicate addresses the first error you receive, but you have correctly identified that with the way the constructor works right now it's not possible to initialize the member in the initializer list. I don't think it was correct to close it with that duplicate

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks, I have implemented your solution and it seems to work great. I will clarify the question and ask for it to be reopened (I see a link for that). If you have time to write that up as an answer that would be great :)

Comment: `LightweightNeuralNetwork` is nothing more than a `std::unique_ptr<generic::LightweightNeuralNetwork<double>> m_impl`. It should be moveable. There is no reason for it not to be. You should file a bug and request to make it moveable, or perhaps implement this change yourself and submit a PR. Then you can write a function that returns a `LightweightNeuralNetwork`, and call if from the initializer list in your main class. Having another level of indirection there is pure waste, so avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork` is not moveable, which, as @
n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. pointed out, seems to be a bug in the library, as there doesn't appear to be any reason for it not to be.

If you don't want to or for some reason cannot make changes to the library yourself (and waiting for it to be fixed is an unacceptable delay) then you can simply replace `lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork * lwtnn_neural;` with `std::unique_ptr<lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork> lwtnn_neural;` and in the constructor replace `lwtnn_neural = new lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork(config.inputs, config.layers, config.outputs);` with `lwtnn_neural = std::make_unique<lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork>(config.inputs, config.layers, config.outputs);`

---

However adding move construction and assignment is pretty trivial, so you can consider doing that yourself, e.g.:

```
LightweightNeuralNetwork(LightweightNeuralNetwork&& other) noexcept : 
  m_impl(std::move(other.m_impl) {}

LightweightNeuralNetwork& operator=(LightweightNeuralNetwork&& other) noexcept {
  if (this != &other) {
    m_impl = std::move(other.m_impl);
  }
  return *this;
}
```

And then you can have a non-pointer member in combination with an extra function to initialize the `lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork` in a member initializer list, e.g.:

```
// Moved all the logic from the constructor body into separate function
static lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork createNetwork(const std::string& inputFile) {
  // The input file is read into a stringstream
  std::ifstream input(inputFile);
  std::stringstream sin;
  sin << input.rdbuf();
  input.close();
  // build the graph
  lwt::JSONConfig config = lwt::parse_json(sin);
  return lwt::LightweightNeuralNetwork(config.inputs, config.layers, config.outputs);
}

TNeuralNetworkLWTNN::TNeuralNetworkLWTNN(std::string inputFile) : 
  lwtnn_neural(createNetwork(inputFile)) // function used to create object for member
  {}
```